# Modify xml attribute based on parent tags attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to modify the attribute of an XML node, based on an attribute of it's parent node.

I think it will be better explained with an example...so:

I have an xml file that looks like this:

```xml
<pdf2xml>
    <page number="1">
        <text top="100" />
    </page>
    <page number="2">
        <text top="100" />
        <text top="50" />
    </page>
</pdf2xml>
```

I'm currently ordering the text nodes by 'top' within each page with the following xslt template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">     

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pdf2xml/page">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select=".">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
                    <xsl:sort select="@top" data-type="number"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I later refer to all the text nodes as one long array using `getElementsByTagName("text")` - so what I want to do, is make `text@[top] = 5000 * page@[number]` - so that all my text `top` attributes are sequential through the whole document.

I've had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035682/replace-xml-attribute-based-on-the-other-attribute-value), which helped, but I'm struggling to see how (if I even can?) apply that to a dynamic value, dependent on the position in the hierachy of each text node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a template matching the `top` attribute itself, from where you can refer to the page number as `../../@number` (in XPath an attribute node is not a child of its containing element, but the containing element *is* the parent of the attribute node):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pdf2xml/page">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
                <xsl:sort select="@top" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text/@top">
        <xsl:attribute name="top">
            <xsl:value-of select=". + (../../@number * 5000)" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You might prefer to make things more explicit by using `ancestor::page[1]/@number` instead of `../../@number` to make it clearer to future readers of the code that it's the nearest containing `page` you're trying to reach.

Comment: `. * ../../@number` was the magic I was unaware of! Thank you - I didn't realise you could manipulate the values so directly.

Comment: @Chris sorry, I messed up the expression to start with, this version should work better...

Comment: Not a problem, I'd spotted that and corrected - just couldn't get an edit in! ;) Thank you!